# Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

Tags: c#

Two table column in SQL created as nullable, I have created the col like this:

```
ALTER TABLE Unittype
    ADD BaseUnitTypeid int;
ALTER TABLE PRODUCT
    ADD BaseUnitTypeid int;
```

Now what I am trying to do is below in product

```
[Column, Nullable] 
public int BaseUnitTypeid { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("CloudBaseUnitTypeID")] [Association(QueryExpressionMethod = nameof(GetCloudBaseUnitTypeid), CanBeNull = true)] 
public string CloudBaseUnitTypeID { get; set; }

[Association(QueryExpressionMethod = nameof(GetLocalBaseUnitTypeid), CanBeNull = true)] 
public int LocalBaseUnitTypeID { get; set; } = 0;


public static Expression<Func<Product, IDataContext, IQueryable<string>>> GetCloudBaseUnitTypeid()
{
    return (offerProd, db) => db.GetTable<UnitType>().Where(prod => prod.UnitTypeId == (offerProd.LocalBaseUnitTypeID)).Select(x => x.CloudID).Take(1);
}

public static Expression<Func<Product, IDataContext, IQueryable<int>>> GetLocalBaseUnitTypeid()
{
    return (offerProd, db) => db.GetTable<UnitType>().Where(prod => prod.UnitTypeId == offerProd.UnitTypeId).Select(x => x.BaseUnitTypeid).Take(1);
}
```

While `GetCloudBaseUnitTypeid()` it is throwing an error

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object

but when I changed `BaseUnitTypeid` to "not nullable", it worked fine.

Why is it throwing an error while the column is defined as nullable? Is there any way that I can keep still as nullable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.